# Выделение через Pen-tool

Tags: photoshop

Выделил Pen-tool'ом (перо) сложный объект с внутренними областями выделения, а вот как сделать на основе этого пути выделение (Маке Selection) не понимаю, оно создаётся, но только по периметру, без внутренних участков.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, разобрался. Забыл, изучить его настройки. Вычитание помогло!
А минус за что? Превращаетесь в Pikabu?
Или здесь ресурс только для гуру?